# Selecting first (earliest) occurrence from TIMESTAMP in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a simple table like below. How do you I select unique user_ids showing the earliest log in time?

For below, my output should include only two rows showing user_id 344 logging in at on 2021-10-05 and user_id 345 logging in at  2021-10-03

| user_id | log_in_time |
| --- | --- |
| 344 | 2021-10-05 03:22:17 UTC |
| 344 | 2021-10-09 03:46:45 UTC |
| 345 | 2021-10-03 03:18:03 UTC |
| 345 | 2021-10-04 01:29:41 UTC |

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id, min(log_in_time) as [earliest_log_in_time]
 from [simple table]
 group by user_id
```